# finding median via function in c plus plus

Tags: c++, arrays

Hi I have made this function to find the median but instead of getting 3.5 i m getting 3. i dont understand why? Can anybody please guide me. Thank you. :)

```
int median(int array[], int n)
{
  float med =0 ;
  int a=0;
  int b=0;
  float newMed=0;
    if (n % 2 ==0)
      a=n/2;
      b=(n/2)-1;
     med = (array[a] + array[b]);
     newMed = (med/2);
 //else
 //med = (n+1)/2;

 return newMed;
 }

int main()
{
  int array[6] = {1,2,3,4,6,7};
  cout<<"the median is: "<<median(array,6)<<"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `int median(int array[], int n)` (as function returning an `int` can not return `3.5`) to

```
float median(int array[], int n)  // Return type int -> float
```

When your return type is `int`, return value `newMed` calculated as `3.5` is implcitly converted to an `int` which is `3`. This code is roughly equivalent to:

```
cout<<"the median is: "<< (int)median(array,6)<<"\n";
```

---

If you compile your program with proper warning flags (`-W -Wall -O2`, O2 optimization flag for regress analysis), compiler should warn you about such mistake.

Comment: Is there any way of Getting 3.5 without changing the function type int? i mean to get floating numbers by doing something inside the function?

Comment: Return the sum and divide by 2 in caller. Or pass a float pointer/reference to collect the result. `int` can not return `3.5`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
#define  SIZE 7
float getMedian( int *arry,int size) {
    sort(arry, arry + size);
    if(size%2){
      return arry[(size/2)];
    }
    else {
        return ((arry[(size/2) -1]+arry[size/2])/2);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int intArray[7] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

    //Now we call the sort function

   std::cout << getMedian (intArray,SIZE) << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of sorting the entire array it's possible to use [nth_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) to only sort it half-way to the point we care about. In this case with 7 elements it won't make any difference but on larger arrays it could because we're doing less work to find the middle elements.